# review ratings not displaying on the stars in Django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have number of ratings in the database that needs to be displayed on the stars.
This is what I tried,

```
models.py:-
class Doctors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    ratings = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default="")

views.py:-
def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.POST.get("search")
        result = Doctors.objects.filter(speciality__icontains=search)
        return render(request, "result.html", {"result": result})
    return render(request, "result.html")

result.html:-
{% for res in result %}
<div class="desc">
<h6 class="primary-text">{{res.name}}</h6>
</div>
<div class="ratings" id="ratings">
<i class="fa fa-star {% if res.ratings >= 1 %} rating-color {% endif %}"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star {% if res.ratings >= 2 %} rating-color {% endif %}"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star {% if res.ratings >= 3 %} rating-color {% endif %}"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star {% if res.ratings >= 4 %} rating-color {% endif %}"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star {% if res.ratings >= 5 %} rating-color {% endif %}"></i>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTgrS.png)
[This is what I am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhqf1.png)

Comment: How does the DOM look like? Is `rating-color` added to the `i` elements? And how is `rating-color` defined in your CSS style?